# Why .gitconfig [includeIf] does not work?

Tags: git, macos, command-line-interface, git-config

System settings:
`MacOS Catalina 10.15.6`

```
> git --version
git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
```

file: `~/.gitconfig` :

```
[user]
    name = nickname
    email = nickname@gmail.com
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Business"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-work
```

file: `~/.gitconfig-work` :

```
[user]
    name = First Last
    email = fl@work.com
```

Output when trying to check the configuration on terminal:

```
(base) MBP-Name:~ myname$ cd ~/Business/
(base) MBP-Name:Business myname$ git config --get user.name
nickname
```

I have tried both relative `~` and absolute `/` paths either for `gitdir` and `path` in the config file. On each change I am restarting the bash. Also, I have read several other stackoverflow questions with no success. Some of them where suggesting adding the `i` option for case insensitivity but it didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is `~/Business/` a repository (working tree)? If not hint: `includeIf` works only in **repositories** under `~/Business/` but not in a non-repo directory.

Comment: @phd You were totally right. I had to change ``` "gitdir:~/Business"``` to ``` "gitdir:~/Business/"``` and hit the command inside a repo folder```. Thank you <3

Comment: @entropyfever That's helpful. You should add it as an answer... :D

Comment: Took me a few hours to figure out why it doesn't work. The overridden config will only be visible when you are in a git directory, otherwise it always shows the global values.

Comment: Had a similar issue to what author is describing, but with a different root cause.
includeIf in global git config should be written AFTER user configuration. In my case, I had includeIf first thing in config and it didn't work

Answer (score 13):

I tried removing the double quotes and typing it again. weirdly it worked. since I copied the text from https://blog.gitguardian.com/8-easy-steps-to-set-up-multiple-git-accounts/

Comment: This was the problem for me, the difference between the non-standard quote marks (“ ”) and standard quote marks (" "). 
Remove the fancy quote marks and its works

Comment: Exactly the same issue for me. Changed the "fancy" quote marks, and it worked well.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is starting to be an old question, but I had a similar problem and the solution for it was dead simple, so I'll share it in case anyone has thee same problem: the problem was simply that your dir should have a slash (`/`) at the end...

So in the case of the OP,

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Business"]
```

Should simply become

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Business/"]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

I spent a lot of time trying to debug this but every time didn't work.

So I decided to delete and start fresh.
This is what I did:

Create `.gitconfig`

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/home/"]
path = ~/.gitconfig.home
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/work/"]
path = ~/.gitconfig.work
```

Create `.gitconfig.work`

```
[user]
name = My Name
email My work email
```

Create `.gitconfig.home`

```
[user]
name = My Name
email My personal email
```

**Then, I initialized git (`git init`) in both folders: `~/Documents/work/` and `~/Documents/home/`.**

After initializing everything work as expected.

I hope it helps you in case you are experiencing this issues.

Tested in Mac and Windows.

Comment: thanks for the help. the secret was `git init` on those folders

Comment: `git init` on the folder gets this working

Comment: Weirdly this isn't working for me. I had it set up with my home as default and work only applied to one area, but changed it to this setup to try to fix the issue, but no luck. All git commits have the correct user, but `git push` tries to use the wrong user. Even nuking the repo and re-cloning it didn't work.

Comment: For anyone else having a similar issue I tracked down what it was: if you have an `~/.ssh/config` file that sets a user name for your remote that will always take precedence over the git config. I.e. if you've set up an `IdentityFile` configuration for your remote, make sure you *don't* set the `User` property.

Comment: It's especially hidden as for public repositories on GitHub the user won't matter for cloning, but it will for pushing.

Answer (score 3):

I myself also had issues with my .gitconfig. I read the docs a few times, searched Stackoverflow and some blogposts. I though I have tried every possible solution for it: relative paths, trailing slashes, different quotes, et cetera. Non of the solutions I tried actually worked.

I got to the point I just tried to include a file using `[include]`, but with no success either.

After a few hours of trying and searching for answers, I came across a post that mentioned a `.gitconfig` to be included could also be a `.txt` file.
I changed the files from `.gitconfig-{company}` to `gitconfig-{company}.txt` and renamed the paths in the global `.gitconfig`, and everything worked instantly!

I hope this works for you, and future googlers.

Comment: I think the `.gitconfig` file has to end in `.gitconfig`, like `.github.gitconfig`, which is what I use

Comment: The global one does. But whenever I tried to import a file via the `[includeIf]`, I needed to add the `.txt` extension in order to make it work. It took me a long time to figure out, since every example said it should just be `.gitconfig-{company}`.

Maybe there is a setting enabled somewhere that causes my system to only check for `.txt`. Maybe someone also struggles with that and find that the `.txt` works for them too :)

Comment: Did you try `.{company}.gitconfig`?

Comment: Could try that. Thanks for the insight. The examples said it didn't matter , but it seems more logical that way.
I just wanted to let you guys know that a `.txt` file also suffices.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to add both users to the same gitconfig file and it wasn't working for me. So, I created a gitconfig for each user and it worked!!

> ~/.gitconfig

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Documents/Personal/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig_personal

[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Documents/Work/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig_work
```

> ~/.gitconfig_personal

```
[user]
    name = Your Personal Name
    email = your_personal@email.com
```

> ~/.gitconfig_work

```
[user]
    name = Your Work Name
    email = your_work@email.com
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is the trailing '/' at the end of the dir. You'll see even when people did other things to 'fix it' they have added a trailing slash and don't even realize it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35031942)

Comment: This is the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

1. Make sure to test this `includeIf` business before assuming that it just works (just like anything else? ‍♀️). It seems to not work (right away) in a lot of circumstances.
2. For some reason, `git` did not pick up the change until I use `git config` to make some random change. (Note: I am on win10)

#### Long Version

Firstly, make sure to look through the other answers in this post, since every post seems to contribute a different potential issue.

Now this is what happened to me (NOTE: I am on Windows 10):

1. Open `~/.gitconfig` and add the entry `includeIf` entry

   - e.g.:

     ```
     [includeIf "gitdir:~/x/"]
     path = ~/.x.gitconfig
     ```
2. Create the custom `~/.x.gitconfig` file and override some setting, e.g. set `a.b = c` (make sure its different from the default, so you can test it at first)
3. NOTE: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311760/2228771) claims that this won't affect old directories, but I have not tested it.
4. Go to the directory (`cd ~/x`) and test. E.g. I tried `git config a.b` and it gave me the wrong value.
5. I realized the folder was not yet `git init`ed, so I ran `git init`, and it still did not work.
6. **Sln**: I made a random local config change via `git config some thing`
7. Tested again and it worked and always picked up all changes immediately right after that. It now works!

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

In my case `[includeIf]` didn't work because my config is on the **C:** drive (`C:\Users\User\.gitconfig`), but my working projects are on the **D:** drive (`D:\Projects\Work\`).

### Solution

In my case it should be:

`[includeIf "gitdir/i:Work/"]`

Instead of:

`[includeIf "gitdir/i:~/Work/"]`

[Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes)

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck by the strange behaviors after I use `[includeIf "gitdir:~/foo"]`, it works sometimes, and sometimes doesn't.

Therefore I digged into [Git's `git-config` official documentation Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes):

> `gitdir`
>
> The data that follows the keyword `gitdir:` is used as a glob pattern. If **the location of the .git directory** matches the pattern, the include condition is met.
>
> **The .git location may be auto-discovered, or come from `$GIT_DIR` environment variable**. If the repository is auto discovered via a .git file (e.g. from submodules, or a linked worktree), the .git location would be the final location where the .git directory is, not where the .git file is.

I personally feel this design is bizarre though... It means the `[includeIf "gitdir:~/foo"]` in your `~/.gitconfig` can be triggered when you `cd ~/foo/existed_project && git fetch` though, BUT will not be triggered when you `cd ~/foo && git clone`, because the directory `~/foo/.git/` is not existed...

Explicitly setting env var `GIT_DIR=~/foo` seems also not work (maybe because `~/foo/.git` is still not existed?).

As far as I know, a simpler workaround to solve this is to `~/foo && git init`... I don't know if there's a better or canonical practice after DuckDuckGoing for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing `~` with absolute path , but i don't konw why.
below is my config

```bash
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/name/**"]
path = /Users/name/.gitconfig-personal
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/name/Desktop/work/**"]
path = /Users/name/.gitconfig-work

[core]
excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
```

/Users/name/.gitconfig-work file like this

```bash
[user]
name = Jack
email = Jack@web.site
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was to expect git to overwrite some config sections of main .gitconfig in the others.

However, you need to explicitly set these configs in each git config file and should not set them in main .gitconfig file.

For instance, main .gitonfig file should not include user config if your .gitconfig-work and .gitconfig-personal users are different:

```
[user]
    name = Jane Does
    email = jabne@gmail.com
    signingkey = ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This will only affect future projects created with git init. Previous projects will remain unchanged

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33101923)

Comment: Incorrect information